# Cassandra CQL Shell abre e fecha

Tags: banco-de-dados, nosql, cassandra

Comecei a estudar sobre o CassandraDB, mas estou usando o Windows. Quando inicio o serviço 'DataStax DDC Server 3.9.0' recebo um erro. Vendo os logs, tem o erro:

```
Arquivo: datastax_ddc_server-stderr.xxx.log:  
2018-10-19 10:32:28 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized  
Invalid yaml: file:/C:/Program%20Files/DataStax-DDC/apache-cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml  
Error: while scanning a double-quoted scalar; found unknown escape character D(68);  in 'reader', line 168, column 40:  
     ... og_directory: "C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\commitlog"
```

No arquivo `datastax_ddc_server-stdout.xxx.log`:

```
2018-10-19 10:32:28 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized  
INFO  13:32:29 Configuration location: file:/C:/Program%20Files/DataStax-DDC/apache-cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml  
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/C:/Program%20Files/DataStax-DDC/apache-cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml  
Error: while scanning a double-quoted scalar; found unknown escape character D(68);  in 'reader', line 168, column 40:  
         ... og_directory: "C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\commitlog" 
                                         ^
ERROR 13:32:29 Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/C:/Program%20Files/DataStax-DDC/apache-cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
 Error: while scanning a double-quoted scalar; found unknown escape character D(68);  in 'reader', line 168, column 40:
     ... og_directory: "C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\data\commitlog"
```

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui resolver o problema ainda, porém, consegui contornar a situação. Dentro do diretório do cassandra tem um arquivo chamado 'cassandra.bat', rodei este arquivo e em seguida iniciei o shell cql do cassandra, após isso consegui trabalhar normalmente com o banco.

Ainda não tive tempo de analisar o arquivo.bat, mas minha solução estará lá, ao menos o direcionamento dela.

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas maneiras de iniciar o servidor do cassandra, a primeira é definindo a localização da pasta bin do cassandra dentro da variável de sistema `PATH` e logo após abrir o prompt de comando e simplesmente digitar `cassandra`.

A segunda maneira é navegar pelo prompt de comando até a pasta do cassandra e depois para dentro da pasta bin usando o comando `cd`. Após entrar na pasta bin do cassandra basta digitar `cassandra.bat -f`.

Após executar o comando o servidor estaria ligado e você deve manter a janela do prompt de comando aberta. Caso você fechar a janela do prompt de comando o servidor sera desligado.

Para poder administrar o banco de dados você  possui duas opções, a primeira delas é baixar o Datastax DevCenter e trabalhar com tudo via interface gráfica. A segunda opção é utilizar o comando cqlsh no prompt de comando. Caso você tiver efetuado o esquema de adicionar a variável de sistema basta utilizar `cqlsh` no prompt de comando, caso contrario basta navegar para dentro da basta bin do cassandra novamente e executar o comando `cqlsh.bat`.

Vale lembrar que dependendo do seu windows talvez você precisara executar um comando que liberara o uso de scripts arquivos .bat externos (que são os arquivos do cassandra).